# webapp back button not working when minimize

Tags: iphone, web-applications, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, fullscreen

i had web app using jquery mobile framework, i added back button there using this code:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="g" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a data-icon="back" data-role="button" data-add-back-btn="true" data-direction="reverse"  data-rel="back" >Back</a> 
</div>
```

its working when normal stage and even minimize mobile safari... but when minimize my webapp fullscreen mode then reaopen my back button not working, for example: i link page A to B while page B i minimize my fullscreen webapp, then when return to Page B again if i click back burron how to go back Page A.?